# Are there any formal alternative expressions for "hold the urine"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there any similar and formal expressions to say "hold the urine"?

I'd like to know some formal expression to say "hold the urine".

Comment: About all I've ever heard are several versions of "just hold it", plus "cross your legs".

Comment: Could you clarify the meaning of this expression, it's not common where I come from.

Comment: Is this a formal translation of 'take the piss' or a slightly odd way of saying 'don't urinate now'? Either way, it isn't idiomatic, at least for British English, so your meaning isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

There are no direct way to say "hold the urine", like there're no direct way to say "pee".

Almost everytime, you don't explicitly say: I hold the pee/poo.

However, you can use "I really need to go to the toilet", that's formal.

Comment: There's always "I need to see a man about a horse".

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to say "hold your urine" where I come from. If someone says "I have to urinate," you can answer:

*"Cross your legs and think about the desert."* (Good for mixed company.)

*"Tie a knot in it."* (To a man.)

*"Don't break the seal."* (Common among beer drinkers.)

*"Just keep dancing."* (General use.) (US)